# How to extract HTML tags without/excluding text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How should one extract just the tags with attributes included without the text?

Source:

```
<div style='some style' id='some id'>
some text
</div>
<a href='some url'>some link</a>
<img src='some url' />
```

Result:

```
"<div style='some style' id='some id'> </div> <a href='some url'> </a> <img src='some url' />"
```

Comment: you can use a RegExp to replace the chars in-between the tags: `str.replace(/>[^<]+?</g,"> <")` if your markup is valid or even just well-formed, this works perfectly.

Comment: @dandavis At the moment I am holding off that approach as a last resort...

Comment: the other easy option would be to turn the markup into a dom, remove the textNodes, then get the outerHTML, but that can change the markup quite a bit (quoting attribs, converting entities, turning `disabled` into `disabled=""`, etc. it would convert your apos-delimited attribs into quotes, for example. not sure if that's a dealbreaker to your needs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sample = $("<div><div style='some style' id='some id'>some text</div><a href='some url'>some link</a><img src='some url' /></div>");
output = removeText(sample);

function removeText(node){
    node = $(node);
    $.each( node.contents(), function(){
        if(this.nodeType == 3) {
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        }else {
            removeText(this);
        }

    });
    return node;
}
```

output:

```
<div><div style="some style" id="some id"></div><a href="some url"></a><img src="some url"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery 'clone':

```
    <div id="some-id">lalala</div>

    var $copy = $('#some-id').clone().html('');//create a copy and remove text
    var str = $('<div>').append($copy);//covert jquery obj to string
```

[image: try it in console]